# How to edit/modify/replace text in pdf by using python?

Tags: python, pymupdf

Below is my code.

```
import fitz  # import PyMuPDF...for whatever reason it is called fitz

doc = fitz.open("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\abcd.pdf")  # the file with the text you want to change
search_term = "original"

for page in doc:
    found = page.search_for(search_term)  # list of rectangles where to replace
    for item in found:
        font = page.get_fonts(item)
        page.add_redact_annot(item, '')  # create redaction for text
        page.apply_redactions()  # apply the redaction now
        page.insert_text(item.bl - (0, 3), "modified")


doc.save("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\abcd.pdf")
```

This code is well-working but i have two questions.
First, how to apply original's attribute like size or font?
Second, why use (0, 3)? How about (0, 1) or (0,5)?

I want to change the text without any awkwardness.
Please let me know how to apply attribute.

Comment: (1) Do read the documentation of [page.insert_text](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.insert_text)! (2) Before removing old text, extract all its information that you need to apply to the new text (color, font, font size, insertion point) during insert. Getting the right font is the hardest, because the one present in the PDF is probably unusable: it normally only is a **_subset_** of the original, not containing all the characters needed by your new text.